# How to make nagios not send messages during the night and morning to send all the remaining errors

Tags: email, nagios

I have Nagios checking service status and sending SMS messages about service status.

Some problems are not important at night and prefer to not send them at night.

```
define timeperiod{
    timeperiod_name non_work
    alias       Non work hours
    sunday      00:00-24:00
    monday      00:00-09:00,18:00-24:00
    tuesday     00:00-09:00,18:00-24:00
    wednesday   00:00-09:00,18:00-24:00
    thursday    00:00-09:00,18:00-24:00
    friday      00:00-09:00,18:00-24:00
    saturday    00:00-24:00
}
```

However, in the morning I would like that all the problems, not just new would be sent.
How can I configure that?

Or nagios do not have this functions?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, you just don't want to receive text messages during the night for certain problems, but upon work hours want to receive all the warnings you ***would have received*** if the warnings were being sent.  This isn't something that is built into Nagios, but is something that you can/should send over to the development community for consideration.